# CentOS : need to allow 8080 port in iptables

Tags: centos

Can't let my firewall to accept incoming connections to 8080...

```
# iptables -L -v -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
8   704 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
5   971 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:22
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:8080
0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:8080 /* phj8080 */


Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 648 bytes)
pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

And here is netstat data. 11080/app in forst row is an app that listen port 8080..
All works fine just when i turn this firewall off :) 
When iptables is On, i can work with 8080 only inside local machine.

Ho i can allow this damned 8080 port for all ? :)

```
# netstat -plnt
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8080                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      11080/app
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22                  0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1532/sshd
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1608/master
tcp        0      0 :::22                       :::*                        LISTEN      1532/sshd
tcp        0      0 ::1:25                      :::*                        LISTEN      1608/master
```

Answer (score 2):

You have a `reject` all on line 5, you can deleted it with this command

```
iptables -D INPUT 5
```

And move (add it again) it to the end of the list with

```
iptables -A INPUT -j REJECT
```

Then (if every thing works correctly) you should save the rules with

```
iptables-save > /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

Comment: I suggest clarifying why this needs to be done.  I was going to answer the same thing but with some details since OP obviously doesn't understand how the filters are processed.